# VS c++ compiler on server compiler for free licence

Tags: c++, visual-studio, server, compilation

- "MSBuild Tools" is a free MS compiler used by VS which can be deployed and used without licences : GREAT but managed code only !
- It seems the C/C++ compile versions used by VS can't be installed in stand alone and then are not licence free. Nearest tool available seems to be VS Express Edition (but we need it on a multi user server and we can't set multi product key)

Would you have any idea in mind to use the same compiler than VS (not GCC,...) for free on a compilation server ?

Ty for help

--- EDITs

- I work for a company with more than 5 developpers :)
- When I did DL MS Build Tools 2015, I got a very small setup (24Mo) witch needs only 200Mo once installed and only contains managed build tools

Comment: Use a version that can legally be deployed on a compilation server, like VS2017?

Comment: Are you an individual developer, a student, or an open source developer?

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Comment: By the way who said "managed code only"?

Comment: For Build Tools 2015, there are two versions (C++ and managed). For BT2017, they are both together, right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and thanks for your help wich guided me to the solution.

It's necessary to log in my.visualstudio.com in order to be able to download MS Build Tools :
They exist in different versions, I did choose :

- C++ Build Tools 2015U3
- .Net Build Tools 2015U3
- Build Tools 2017 - 15.9 (they Added C++ and managed Inside the same setup)

Those compilers cover my needs but you can find Build Tools 2013 for .Net (not C++) and no Build Tools for older versions.

Please note they are free and don't need a licence key.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options for a stand-alone compiler that is ABI compatible with Visual Studio:

- The [visual studio build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) can be used under the same license terms as visual studio. In other words, if you have a licensed version OR you qualify for the Community edition, you can use these.
- Clang produces binaries that are ABI-compatible with visual studio, so you can mix and match. A recent push by Microsoft allows it to produce [PDB files for Visual Studio](http://blog.llvm.org/2017/08/llvm-on-windows-now-supports-pdb-debug.html) as well.

Comment: I did solve with classic CL.exe compiler, but I'll look later for Clang use in our projects, thanks